# как подождать пока все запросы пройдут?

Tags: ruby, test-automation

Как можно проверить и подождать что все эти реквесты прошли на странице?

Для AJAX'а есть такой метод:

```
def wait_for_ajax_requests
  wait_until { page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active === 0') }
  rescue Timeout::Error
   raise 'Ran out of time waiting for Ajax.requests to be empty.'
end
```

Какой метод нужно использовать тут?

[image: asp. net request]

Comment: Какой фреймворк? Selenium? Watir? Poltergeist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST-запрос у вас на картинке - это тоже AJAX. Только вызов сделан не через JQuery. И ваш код "для AJAX" для него не работает.

Для MS Ajax код проверки на наличие запросов выглядит примерно так:

```
var requstManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
var result = requstManager._request == null && !requstManager._processingRequest;
```

Эффективного метода дождаться AJAX-запросов нет. Есть частные решения. У меня на одном из проектов пришлось писать аж 4 разных wait-а для разных видов запросов. 
И все равно такой подход оказался нестабильным.

В общем случае нельзя точно дождаться момента, когда "AJAX отработал" - потому что слишком многое в js делается асинхронно или через таймауты - и завершение запроса к серверу ничего не говорит о том, успело ли все "отработать до конца".

Вы пишете UI-тесты, это практически самые полные из интеграционных тестов. Они не долны лезть внутрь приложения, даже на уровень общения браузера с сервером.

Вместо "ожидания завершения ajax" нужно использвовать явные ожидания результата - появления того или иного контрола, который должен быть результатом действия. Т.е. вы должны буквально воспроизводить тесткейсы. В кейсах обычно написано - нажали на заголовок второго таба - увидели второй таб. Вот именно это и должно быть в коде автотестов.

Все остальное - нестабильные костыли, которые будут регулярно давать ложные срабатывания, из-за которых тесты придется активно поддерживать, из-за чего вы на них забьете.